# Get PHP7.3 working with Apache2 on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: apache2, php

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache2
PHP 7.3

My .../phpinfo.php file is being displayed as text.

I have run a2dismod on php7.0, 7.1, and 7.2 justtobesure.

I ran

```
$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.3 is already the newest version (7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

but

```
$ a2enmod php7.3
ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!
```

Is there some other package I need to install?

Thanks for any help.  It's probably a semicolon, but I have been searching for hours.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by doing:

```
a2enconf php7.3-fpm
```

After this, `phpinfo.php` works and is no longer displayed as text.